# Старт сессии на другом домене при передаче информации через заголовки методом POST

Tags: php, post, header

Пожалуйста, помогите найти ответ на вопрос, самостоятельно это сделать мне не удалось.
Логика работы такова:

1. Есть 2 сайта, у каждого своя база данных.
2. При регистрации на первом информация про пользователя заносятся в 1-ю базу данных.
3. …
4. На втором сайте есть возможность аутентификации из внешней базы данных. При этом логин и пароль из внешней базы копируются в свою базу.

Вопрос, собственно, в третьем пункте.

1. Если я из первого сайта отправляю логин пароль через форму, то происходит перенаправление на второй сайт, информация заносится в его базу данных, аутентификация проходит, сессия стартует.
2. Моя задача же состоит в том, чтобы во время регистрации на первом сайте информация отправлялась методом POST на второй через заголовки.

Скрипт на втором сайте работает, информация во вторую базу заносится, но сессия не стартует. Когда я перехожу на второй сайт мне нужно все равно заходить там через форму. Код скрипта на 2-ом сайте, который получает данные от 1-го переданные методом POST:

```html
<?php
session_start();

require_once "config.php";

$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$password = $_REQUEST['password'];

authenticate_user_login($name, $password);
```

Есть ли такая возможность, отправляя информацию через заголовки, стартовать сессию для другого домена?
Если это невозможно, как реализовать такую схему?

Answer (score 1):

Задачу нужно было решать, так что придумал костыли со скрытой формой

```html
<?php
echo '<form id="formid" action="https://site2.com" method="post">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="name" value="'.$login.'">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="password" value="'.$password.'">';
echo '</form>';
?>
```

отправкой данных скриптом на второй ресурс

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#formid').submit();
});
```

и редиректом обратно на первый.

```js
header('Location: https://site1.com');
```

Все очень просто

Но если кто-то сможет объяснить логику происходящего при отправке данных заголовками файлу, который начинает сессию или покажет где подобный пример рассматривался, буду благодарен.